# what is the meaning of "../" in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

while compiling the c++ programs in which i'm using the libxml library it is showing errors at the header files that no file or directory found. I have installed the library but it still showing errors. So i just type the above command after that every thing is working fine but i didn't understand it.

what is the meaning of "../" in UNIX? my command in UNIX is like this "sudo cp -r libxml ../" what it means? how to give relative addresses in UNIX and what are the different wildcard is used.

Comment: http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix1.html

Comment: while compiling the c++ programs in which i'm using  the libxml library it is showing errors at the header files that no file or directory found. I have installed the library but it still showing errors. So i just type the above command after that every thing is working fine but i didn't understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`..` represents the parent directory. For example, if the current directory is `/home/user/` the parent directory is `/home`

`.`  represents the current directory

The command `sudo cp -r libxml ../`  copies the entire directory `libxml` in the parent directory.